# How to write the Captcha?

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

I am developing a registration form in that i want to place the CAPTCHA . i generate a random string but how to convert that into the image other wise how can i develop the CAPTCHA code or any reference. thank you

Comment: Did you mean Captcha? I googled for CAPATACHA.... Thinking it was something new ;-)

Comment: ya captcha sorry for spelling mistake

Comment: See following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx

Comment: This is captcha library in C: http://brokestream.com/captcha.html, probably it won't be too hard to port it to C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/aspnet/) or check out eh blog post "[Captcha Using Asp.Net](http://www.codegeeks.net/captcha-using-aspnet)"  which I wrote sometime back.

Comment: Shoban i referred blog, and i  convert into c# but it is giving some error

Comment: i send the list of errors to the block owner is there any other reference or any thing thank u for response Mr. Shoban

Comment: ya its working i downloaded the source file and place that code in my application thank u dude working

Answer (score 0):

While having a captcha may feel like a good feature, it really isn't: Nowadays there's huge swarms of labor houses in China and such where people are paid for successfully filling out captchas. Yes, that means there's thousands of people manually breaking the system all the time.

If I were implementing my own registration protection/antispam system, I'd go with the more cultural one choice which is just a variation of magic words. What I mean that instead of showing barely readable garble, I'd add a small intellectual puzzle and a text field for it's answer, for example asking *how much is seven plus six minus one* is currently a lot better at detecting both bots and stupid users.