# How do I create my own captcha and verify it in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

How do I create my own captcha and test that response is generated by a person? is it possible to do it in asp.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768582/how-to-write-the-captcha ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [reCAPTCHA](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html) with ASP.NET.

Sign up for a free app key [here](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha), download the [library](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest) and follow the [quick start](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own images of numbers/words from paint by doodling and store the file location and corresponding string in the database. You could later randomly pick an entry, show the image and then verify it with the string value column.

Or you could use external service like http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha